# Proving that $1+λ^2$ is an eigenvalue of $I+A^2$ where $λ$ is an eigenvalue of matrix $A$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

So $Ax = λx$;

$A(Ax) = λ(Ax) \to (A^2)x = (λ^2)x$

I kind of dont know how to get the $1$ and $I$ here...

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What does $A^{2\lambda} = \lambda^{2x}$ mean?  In one, you are exponentiating a matrix to a (probably) real exponent.  In the other you're taking a real number to a vector power?

Comment: well they supposed to be separate.. ill edit it

Comment: What does the first line $A\lambda=\lambda x$ mean ??

Comment: You should use MathJax to clarify these typographic issues.

Comment: My bad for the typos... ://

Comment: Just add $x$ to both sides.  Done.

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4020414/prove-that-1lambda2-is-an-eigenvalue-of-ia2-assuming-that-lambda-is-an-e)

Answer (score 1):

$Ax= \lambda x$ implies that

$$(I+A^2)x=x+A^2x=x+A(\lambda x)=x+\lambda Ax=x+\lambda^2x= (1+ \lambda^2)x$$

Answer (score 1):

$$Ax=\lambda x\to A^2x=\lambda^2x$$

You already did that. From here, sum $Ix=x$ on both sides and get

$$A^2x=\lambda^2x\to A^2x+Ix=\lambda^2x+x\to (A^2+I)x=(1+\lambda^2)x.$$

Answer (score 1):

This is just a special case of a general statement that I wish people learned early and by heart (it is not that hard): if $v$ is an eigenvector of a square matrix $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then for every polynomial $P\in K[X]$, the polynomial $P[A]$ in $A$ acts on $v$ as multiplication by the scalar $P[\lambda]$ (or equivalently, $v$ is also an eigenvector of $P[A]$ with eigenvalue $P[\lambda]$). It applies here with $P=1+X^2$.

The proof of this property uses linearity in $P$ of $P[A](v)$, after the simple proof that $A^k(v)=\lambda^kv$ for all$~k\in\Bbb N$.